# SymPy : Indexed symbols to Summation

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I have an expression like:

```
-(a[1]*b[1] + a[2]*b[2])/((a[1]*b[1] - a[1] + a[2]*b[2] - a[2]))
```

and turn it

```
(-summation(b[omega]*a[omega]))/(summation((b[omega]-1)*a[omega]))
```

where

```
omega = 1,2
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Python loop is probably simpler than what you're trying to do.

Something like

```py
numerator = -sum([b[omega]*a[omega] for omega in range(len(a))])
denominator = sum([(b[omega]-1)*a[omega] for omega in range(len(a))])
result = numerator/denominator
```

If you want something based more around SymPy you'll have to get more involved since Python does not accept symbols when indexing arrays. There are probably many ways to do this but this was the first one that came to mind:

```py
from sympy import *
omega = symbols('omega')
a = symbols('a1 a2')
b = symbols('b1 b2')

class A(Function):
    @classmethod
    def eval(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, Symbol):
            return
        else:
            return a[x]

class B(Function):
    @classmethod
    def eval(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, Symbol):
            return
        else:
            return b[x]

# indexing starts at 0
numerator = -summation(B(omega)*A(omega), (omega, 0, 1))
denominator = summation((B(omega)-1)*A(omega), (omega, 0, 1))
result = numerator/denominator
```